# debian 8 usb headset mic not working

Tags: audio, debian, microphone, usb-headset

I have a fresh debian 8 install, with mate desktop, I am using Logintech H390 USB headset, the sound works fine, the microphone input driver is available but sound recording it's not recording anything. I have tried multiple solutions found online but non if them works. I need to use Zoiper for calling but I also tried to record sounds using arecord from terminal.

Can you please advise me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you verified the mic is not muted? Try installing `pavucontrol` for a start, running it and checking that.

Comment: What's the name of the driver module by the way?

Comment: I have checked the microphone with alsamixer and it's not muted, can you please tell me how I can check the driver module name ?